# Loop async scraping

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, web-scraping, axios

I want to make my personal scraper from wikipedia links I have stored in array but have some problem with async javascript, guess I just don't realize whole async concept enough.

So basically, on every iteration I want my axios.get link to be next thing from data array, and go through whole scraping process, and when it ends it take next link in array and repeat whole process until it loops all array links stated.
I know how to do it in a synchronous way, but this async way is just another universe for me.

```js
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const axios = require('axios');
var fs = require('fs');

const data = ["a","b","c","d","e"];

for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){

let link = data[i];

axios.get(link).then((res) => {

  let $ = cheerio.load(res.data);

    $('div.class.xyz').each(element => {
    let post = $(element).text();
    console.log(post);
    let input = '{' + JSON.stringify(post) + '},' + '\n\n';

    fs.appendFileSync('info.json', input);
    // console.log('Saved!');
    // console.log(index);
  })
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const axios = require('axios');
const fs = require('fs');

(async () => {
    const data = ["a","b","c","d","e"];
    for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        let link = data[i];
        const res = await axios.get(link);
        let $ = cheerio.load(res.data);
        $('div.class.xyz').each(element => {
        let post = $(element).text();
        console.log(post);
        let input = '{' + JSON.stringify(post) + '},' + '\n\n';
        await fs.appendFile('info.json', input);
        // console.log('Saved!');
        // console.log(index);
        });
    }
})();
```

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work.
It shows an "SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function" error when it comes to await fs.appendFile().

Comment: @Javashift His code is valid. It is inside of a async function.

Comment: I presume it is, but it still doesn't work. Which is very interesting. :D